# How to append comments to different UICells in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` with few rows (each row represent a question) and when I hold on a cell I want to add a different comment for each cell.
I have a model where I hardcoded a few questions.
The issue is that when I add a comment, that comment is added to all my cells. And I want to add the comment to the respective cell, not for all of them.
How can I do that?

I will attach here a small project with my issue: [AppendCommentsToCells](https://github.com/tygruletz/AppendCommentsToCells)

Here is the code for my model:

```
import Foundation

class ChecklistItemSection {

    var name: String // name of the section
    var checklistItems: [ChecklistItem] // all items from Checklist

    init(named: String, includeChecklistItems: [ChecklistItem]) {

        name = named
        checklistItems = includeChecklistItems
    }

    class func checklistItemSections() -> [ChecklistItemSection] {

        return [vehicleCheck(), viewingScreen(), batteryUnitAndFridge()]
    }

    // Private methods
    private class func vehicleCheck() -> ChecklistItemSection {

        var checklistItems = [ChecklistItem]()

        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 1, lineID: 1, descript: "Question 1")!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 2, lineID: 2, descript: "Question 2")!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 3, lineID: 3, descript: "Question 3")!)

        return ChecklistItemSection(named: "Section 1", includeChecklistItems: checklistItems)
    }

    private class func viewingScreen() -> ChecklistItemSection {

        var checklistItems = [ChecklistItem]()

        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 4, lineID: 4, descript: "Question 4")!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 5, lineID: 5, descript: "Question 5")!)
        return ChecklistItemSection(named: "Section 2", includeChecklistItems: checklistItems)
    }

    private class func batteryUnitAndFridge() -> ChecklistItemSection {

        var checklistItems = [ChecklistItem]()

        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 6, lineID: 6, descript: "Question 6")!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 7, lineID: 7, descript: "Question 7")!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 8, lineID: 8, descript: "Question 8")!)
        checklistItems.append(ChecklistItem(templateID: 9, lineID: 9, descript: "Question 9")!)
        return ChecklistItemSection(named: "Section 3", includeChecklistItems: checklistItems)
    }
}


class ChecklistItem {

    var template_id: Int
    var line_id: Int
    var descript: String

    var vehicleComment: String = String()
    var trailerComment: String = String()

    init?(templateID: Int,
          lineID: Int,
          descript: String // Question name
        ) {

        self.template_id = templateID
        self.line_id = lineID
        self.descript = descript
    }
}
```

Here is my ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ChecklistVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionsTableView: UITableView!

    //Properties
    var vehicleCommentReceived = String()
    var trailerCommentReceived = String()
    lazy var itemSections: [ChecklistItemSection] = {
        return ChecklistItemSection.checklistItemSections()
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}

extension ChecklistVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let itemCategory = itemSections[section]
        return itemCategory.checklistItems.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return itemSections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "checklistCell", for: indexPath) as! ChecklistCell

        let itemCategory = itemSections[indexPath.section]
        let item = itemCategory.checklistItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.configCell(item)

        cell.vehicleCommentLabel.text = "Vehicle comment: \(vehicleCommentReceived)"

        cell.trailerCommentLabel.text = "Trailer comment: \(trailerCommentReceived)"

        return cell
    }

    // Set the header of each section
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        let checklistItemCategory = itemSections[section]
        return checklistItemCategory.name.uppercased()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 110
    }
}

extension ChecklistVC: ChecklistCellDelegate {

    func tapGestureOnCell() {

        showOptionsOnCellTapped()
    }

    func showOptionsOnCellTapped(){

        let addComment = UIAlertAction(title: " Add Comment", style: .default) { action in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goChecklistAddComment", sender: nil)
        }

        let actionSheet = configureActionSheet()
        actionSheet.addAction(addComment)

        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func configureActionSheet() -> UIAlertController {
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        actionSheet.addAction(cancel)

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad ){
            actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
            actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = []
        }

        return actionSheet
    }
}

// Receive Comments using the Delegate
extension ChecklistVC: ChecklistAddCommentDelegate {

    func receiveVehicleComment(vehicleComment: String?, trailerComment: String?) {
        vehicleCommentReceived = vehicleComment ?? String()
        trailerCommentReceived = trailerComment ?? String()
        questionsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "goChecklistAddComment" {
            let addCommentVC = segue.destination as! ChecklistAddCommentVC
            addCommentVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Here I attached a capture with my issue:

[image]

Thanks for your time if you read this.

Comment: So, your delegate method 'receiveVehicleComment' does not carry any information about the indexPath of the cell being updated. If it does, you can use that in your 'cellForRow: at' method to update only the specific cell.

In other words, you need to track each vehicle's comment individually, preferably, in a array. So, `var vehicleCommentReceived = String()`, should be `var vehicleCommentReceived = [String]()`.

Comment: Function tapGestureOnCell is not propagating any information about which cell is tapped. You can achieve this passing an extra argument cell type of ChecklistCell and then where you have implemented delegated method find the indexpath of the cell using indexPath(for: cell) then use this index to update the selected sell only. Using indexpath updated the datamodel with comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 vars  `vehicleCommentReceived ,trailerCommentReceived` should be properties in  each model object

```
class ChecklistItem {

   var template_id: Int
   var line_id: Int
   var descript: String

   var vehicleComment = "" //<<<<< here
   var trailerComment = ""  // <<<<< here

}
```

When you edit a cell make sure to store it's indexPath and then when saving change the model array that specific indexPath section/row

---

inside the cell

```
// Detect when the user press Long Tap on any cell
@objc func tapEdit(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    delegate?.tapGestureOnCell(self)
}
```

inside the vc declare this

```
 var lastIndexPath:IndexPath!
```

and implement like this

```
func tapGestureOnCell(_ cell:ChecklistCell) {

    showOptionsOnCellTapped(questionsTableView.indexPath(for: cell)!)
}

func showOptionsOnCellTapped(_ indexPath:IndexPath){

    let addComment = UIAlertAction(title: " Add Comment", style: .default) { action in
        self.lastIndexPath = indexPath
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goChecklistAddComment", sender: nil)
    }

    let actionSheet = configureActionSheet()
    actionSheet.addAction(addComment) 
    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func receiveVehicleComment(vehicleComment: String?, trailerComment: String?) {
    let item = itemSections[lastIndexPath.section].checklistItems[lastIndexPath.row]
    item.vehicleComment = vehicleComment ?? ""
    item.trailerComment = trailerComment ?? ""
}
```

then inside `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.vehicleCommentLabel.text = "Vehicle comment: \(item.vehicleComment)" 
cell.trailerCommentLabel.text = "Trailer comment: \(item.trailerComment)"
```

Comment: I have that 2 properties in my model. How can I store the indexPath for that respective cell ?

Comment: And my `cell.vehicleCommentLabel.text = ` how should look ?

Answer (score 0):

You made global var for vehicleCommentReceived ,trailerCommentReceived and displayed them in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
What you need to do is update your datamodel i.e that particular object (of class type ChecklistItemSection) in itemSections  Array.